# Не хватает знаний для создания класса. Помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: python, классы

Написал такой класс:

```
class Sun:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = None
        self.d = None

    def sunset(self):
        self.c = 'sunset'
        return self.calc()

    def sunrise(self):
        self.c = 'sunrise'
        return self.calc()

    def official(self):
        self.d = 'official'
        return self.calc()

    def civil(self):
        self.d = 'civil'
        return self.calc()

    def calc(self):
        x = self.a + self.b + self.c + self.d
        return x
```

Вкратце что мне нужно.
Создать экземпляр со значениями a и b.

```
sun = Sun('a', 'b')
```

Путем вызова функции получить вычисленное значение из метода calc, чтобы получился типа такой запрос со следующим значением:

```
print(sun.sunrise.civil())  # вывод: absunrisecivil
print(sun.sunrise.official())  # вывод: absunriseofficial
print(sun.sunset.official())  # вывод: absunsetofficial
```

Важный момент это то, что sunset и sunrise не должен ничего возвращать самостоятельно, а только со значением либо civil, либо official.

из sun может быть вызван только sunset или sunrise

из sunset может быть вызван только civil и official

из sunrise может быть вызван только civil и official

Описал проблему как мог )))
Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Сделай Sun родительским а sunset и sunrise наследниками. И потом просто вызывай тот или тот класс с параметрами. Если в условия нет что должен быть только 1 класс.

```
class Sun:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = None
        self.d = None

    def official(self):
        self.d = 'official'
        return self.calc()

    def civil(self):
        self.d = 'civil'
        return self.calc()

    def calc(self):
        return self.a + self.b + self.c + self.d

class Sunset(Sun):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.c = 'sunset'

class Sunrise(Sun):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.c = 'sunrise'

sunset = Sunset('a', 'b')
sunrise = Sunrise('a', 'b')

print(sunset.civil())
print(sunrise.official())
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему конечно стоит создать 2 класса:

```py
class SunPos:
  def __init__(self, sun, pos):
    self.startWith = f'{sun.a}{sun.b}{pos}'
  
  def civil(self):
    return f'{self.startWith}civil'
  
  def offical(self):
    return f'{self.startWith}offical'


class Sun:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a; self.b = b
    self.sunrise = SunPos(self, "sunrise")
    self.sunset = SunPos(self, "sunset")
```

Таким образом ваши примеры работают корректно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, частный случай собирания текста в строку работает, но возвращаемая вычисляемая переменная x на самом деле результат вычисления не менее десятка формул, в которых участвуют переменные a, b, c, d, из которых a и b вводятся на этапе создания экземпляра, переменная c получает значение при вызове sunset или sunrise, а переменная d - civil и oficial. При вызове последних все полученные данные a, b, c, d подставляются в формулы (для упрощения я показал это в исходном примере как x = a + b + c + d) и возвращается вычисленное значение x.

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, которые работает как нужно:

```
class SunPos:
    def __init__(self, sun, pos):
        self.a = sun.a
        self.b = sun.b
        self.c = pos
        self.d = None

    def civil(self):
        self.d = 10
        return self.calc()

    def offical(self):
        self.d = 20
        return self.calc()

    def calc(self):

        return self.a * self.b * self.c * self.d


class Sun:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.sunrise = SunPos(self, 1)
        self.sunset = SunPos(self, 15) 
 
x = Sun(10, 5)  
print(x.sunrise.offical())  # Вывод: 1000
```